# how to add more than one value in a single field

Tags: custom-field

I have created a custom field to add attendees for a meeting event. what should be done to add more than one name in the same field. how do i go about? I am new to Sales force

Comment: Answer would be **No**.  But answer can be changed if you could post some code.

Comment: post something what you have tried

Comment: I tried to add lookup filters to existing contacts and users but lookup filters can be linked to one object only.

Comment: I am trying this out on an admin level task without any code. Is it possible.?  Thanks

Comment: Why not use the standard Event/Activity object as that does support multiple contacts being linked, otherwise you could concatenate multiple text strings for attendee names in a text field but it would be of limited use.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve here, you could have many Events of which many People could attend, similarly, many People could potentially attend many Events.

What you've got here is a many-to-many relationship meaning best practice would be to create a [junction object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

What you've (presumably) got is a `Contact` object and an `Event` object, so what you should do is create another object (let's just call it `Attendee`) that has two `master-detail` fields looking at `Contact` and `Event` respectively.

The reason you'd use `master-detail` is because an Attendee record can't exist without an `Event` and someone to go to it (i.e. a `Contact`).

That way, when you want to add `Contact` *John Doe* to your *Apex Session* `Event`, you can create an `Attendee` record. Similarly, if he wanted to go to a *Visualforce Session* `Event`, you could create another `Attendee` record. Furthermore, *Jane Doe* will also be able to go to your *Apex Session* `Event` if she wants to.

All of this can be done without code, as you say here:

> I am trying this out on an admin level task without any code.

Comment: Small typo 'Cont**e**ct' in third paragraph (I don't think I can make a 1 character edit).

Comment: @DerekF Fixed. Just keeping everyone on their toes! ;D

Comment: yay, I passed the test!

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific about what you tried to do, it is unclear with current description.

However, it seems that you want a Lookup field to multiple references, which is not possible. Lookup between two objects is a 1:1 relationship. For 1:N relationships you can make the lookup the other way around (an Attendee references a Meeting, so you can have multiple people connect to the same event),  or for N:N relationships you can create a third object C, which references both an Attendee and a Meeting.